# Redshift View keeps reverting to previous definition

Tags: view, amazon-redshift

I created a view in Redshift that unions two queries, and it works great.  We've thought of a third query that would be worthwhile to add in. eg

```
CREATE VIEW stem_alumni as
SELECT name, email
FROM students
WHERE graduated < 2019 AND major = 'Engineering'

UNION 
SELECT name, email
FROM alumni
WHERE current_employer = 'Google'
```

The problem is when I try to add a third query in

```
UNION
SELECT name, email
FROM professors
WHERE department = 'Engineering'
```

it'll persist for maybe an hour, but then revert to just the original query.

I've run `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...`  and dropping/recreate and get the same result.

How do I get an updated view definition to persist?

**Adding more context**

I created the view using DBeaver, a local SQL client using my specific Redshift credentials.  The view is called by Periscope, our cloud-based BI tool using shared credentials.  Querying the view in Periscope or separate DBeaver windows will eventually revert the view to its original definition.

Comment: Redshift won't revert an object to a previous definition by itself as it will have no record of any previous definitions. My guesses are some outside process is overwriting your change, or possibly you have multiple views with the same name in different schemas (e.g. public) and the default schema is different for the users/sessions/tools.

Comment: Redshift will not do this. Something else is overwriting this view.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift shouldn't have a 'memory' of the view's prior DDL that it could revert to. I'm inclined to agree with the comments that something else is overwriting the updates to the view's DDL after you have committed them.

You should be able to see if something is overwriting the view, by querying the `stl_query` table:

```
SELECT q.starttime
     , u.usename
     , q.querytxt
FROM pg_user u
  JOIN stl_query q ON u.usesysid = q.userid
WHERE POSITION('<view_name>' IN q.querytxt) > 0
ORDER BY q.starttime DESC
;
```

This table only contains recent query information (2-5 days according to the [Redshift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html)), so if you haven't experienced this behavior from the view within that timescale, you may need to force it to occur again in order to troubleshoot who/what is altering the DDL.

Additionally, if the view is being overwritten by a user other than yourself, you will need to query `stl_query` using a super user account (by default, non-super users will only be able to view information for queries that they themselves have executed).